# How to get a column name to display even when there is no data for that column?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

**I want to get the names of the columns of a pandas dataframe even when I don't have data according to certain search criteria**

**that's how it is now:**

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

---

**as I want it to be:**

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [column_name]
Index: []
```

***I select the data directly from the MYSQL DB, I do not save it in memory !***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of your need, but if you want to have a dataframe with column names, you can initialize it with the column names :

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, what you are asking about. But to get names of all DataFrame columns, simply do:

```
df.columns
```